# SimpleXMLElement:difference in Curl and file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

So guys, there is another question.

I've fetched a webpage via curl and constructed XML document:

```
.......
$data = curl_exec($ch1);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

And it worked correctly.

After I used file_get_contents like this

```
......
$file1 = file_get_contents('https://meet77842937.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=report-my-meetings', false, $context);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file1);
```

The last code cannot construct XML, though I able to see through **var_dump** that it receives a page. And I stumbled: I think curl is advanced version of file_get_contents but they must not differ in fetching page. Where are the problems?

**The error**:Extra content at the end of the document

I don't know how but webpage returns some symbol at the end

With regards

Comment: There's some type of authentication? If you authenticate in any way via curl, you can't do the same with file_get_contents.

Comment: I noticed the problem, I didn't store the cookies.